# Plot in MATLAB based on User Input

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am currently plotting a single figure in MATLAB with the following function

```
PlotImage(finalImage, 1, 4, 4, 'Final Image');

function[] = PlotImage(image, y, x, value, name)
subplot(y,x,value);
imagesc(image);
axis image;
title(name);
end
```

I have several 'finalImages' that I want to display based on User Input, i.e Program displays Image 1 by default, then if the Keys 1 - 5 are pressed on the Keyboard it will call PlotImage again with a different Image (Images 1 - 5).

Is there a way to do this? Documentation on KeyPressFcn doesn't seem to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify a `KeyPressFcn` that handles the key press event and also calls all of the necessary plotting commands (and could involve calling `PlotImage`.

```
hfig = figure('WindowKeyPressFcn', @(src,evnt)keypress(evnt));

%// Create 5 "images" to show
finalImages = {rand(4), rand(4), rand(4), rand(4), rand(4)};

function keypress(evnt)
    if ismember(evnt.Key, '12345')
        img = finalImages{str2double(evnt.Key)};
        PlotImage(img, 1, 4, 4, 'Final Image');
    end
end

function PlotImage(img, y, x, value, name)
    subplot(y,x,value);
    imagesc(img);
    axis image;
    title(name);
end
```